# how to print characters in a char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, character

In this code I am using a array of integers as I feel the project Im working on will be alot easier if they are integers. In this array, I assign each position to 46 (ASCII for '.') and print out the (char) version of that ASCII. the reason I made the board int is because I will be placing numbers on this board, yet I want to maintain the '.' that I print.

Current Output:

```
  .   .   .   .   .

  .   .   .   .   .

  .   .   .   .   .

  .   .   .   .   .

  ☺   .   .   .   .
```

Desired Output:

```
  .   .   .   .   .

  .   .   .   .   .

  .   .   .   .   .

  .   .   .   .   .

  1   .   .   .   .
```

Casting with (char) will print the '.' (ASCII 46) just fine, but my numbers will be scewed, as current output dictates.

How can I go about fixing this? I've been staring at this forever.

My code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>


void addRandomNumberToBoard(int *board, int &arrSize)
  {
  srand ((int)time(0)); //seed random

  int destination;

  do destination= rand() % (arrSize-1);

  while ( board[destination] != '.'); // place on a random spot on the board

  int randomNumber=rand() < RAND_MAX / 2 ? 1 : 2; //generate number 1 or 2
  board[ destination] = randomNumber;  //place the number there
  }

int printBoard(int &i, int &arrSize, int *board)
  {

  for(i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
      {
      if( i % 5 == 0 && i!=0) //after every 5 positions print a new line
        cout<<"\n\n";
      cout<<"   "<<(char)board[i]; //this MIGHT be the problem
      }
  }



int main()
  {
  int i;
  int arrSize=25;
  int board[arrSize];

  for(i=0; i<arrSize; i++) //declare all positions as ASCII '.'
    board[i]='.'; //this MIGHT be the other problem

  addRandomNumberToBoard(board,arrSize);
  printBoard(i, arrSize, board);
  }
```

Comment: Assume I'm making a game similar to 2048. An array of char will not be able to hold number bigger than 8, so I will be using an int array

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using a char array? I feel like it would be easier.

I'd comment if I could

Answer (score 0):

The ascii number for the digit `1` is `49`. If you want to print the digit `1`, you'll have to sent the ascii value of `49`. The digits are in order starting at 48 for `0`:

```
0 - 48
1 - 49
2 - 50
3 - 51
4 - 52
5 - 53
6 - 54
7 - 55
8 - 56
9 - 57
```

Therefor you can just add 48 to any of your digits. That will only work for single digits however.

I would recommend you use a char array, as you can see that this gets complicated for little gain.

Check this ascii table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Assume I'm making a game similar to 2048. An array of char will not be able to hold number bigger than 8, so I will be using an int array

Comment: In that case you should be using an array of ints, however, you should just output on the `cout` stream instead of converting them to characters. If you want dots printed in some case, like if the value is 0, just make an if statement and send a '.' to the stream when the int is a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 48 to your values. i.e.

```
board[destination] = randomNumber + 48; // Ascii 49 is '1', 50 is '2'.
```

See an [ascii chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the decimal values of printable characters.